# Dual screen issues on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome, external-monitor

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10. I have a Dell Latitude 7390.

Everything is working fine except for a few external monitor issues:

When connecting 2 monitors (1 through the HDMI port, 1 through Thunderbolt) I used to be able to close the lid and the external monitors would still work. Now, the one connected through HDMI turns off.

When reconnecting the monitors (after being in a meeting, for example), the display get jumbled up and I often have to restart the system.

Any ideas on fixes?

Thanks